# Bound for the inverse of a summation of rank-1 matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given vectors $x_1,\dots,x_T \in R^d$ satisfying $\|x_i\|_2 = 1$, define $A_0 = I$ and $A_t = I + \sum_{i=1}^tx_ix_i^\top$ for $t \geq 1$. We are interested in the following quantity:
\begin{align}
S_{d,T} = \sum_{i=1}^T\|A_{i-1}^{-1}x_i\|_2.
\end{align}
If $d = 1$, it is easy to bound $S_{1,T}$ by $\log T$ as follows:
\begin{align}
S_{1,T} = \sum_{i=1}^T\frac{1}{i} = O(\log T).
\end{align}
Is it true that for $d\geq 2$, we still have the similar bound $S_{d,T} \leq O(poly(d)\log T)$, where $poly(d)$ represents some polynomial of $d$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my answer is correct.

(1) **When $T <= d$, we have
\begin{equation}
S_{d,T} = \sum_{i=1}^T 1= T.
\end{equation}
Here we need $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_T$ are orthogonal with each other.**

It is obvious that $\|A_0^{-1}x_1\| = \|x_1\| = 1$. 
According to Sherman–Morrison formula, we have
\begin{equation}
A_1^{-1} = I - \frac{1}{2}x_1 x_1^T.
\end{equation}
Thus, based on the definition of matrix norm, we have
\begin{equation}
\|A_1^{-1}x_2\| \leq \|A_1^{-1}\|_2,
\end{equation}
Due to $d >=T$, we can found an eigenvector which is orthogonal to $x_1$, and its corresponding eigenvalue is of course $1$, the max eigenvalue of $A$. Thus let $x_2^T x_1 = 0$, the equality in the above equation will be held, i.e., 
\begin{equation}
\|A_1^{-1}x_2\| = 1.
\end{equation}
Next, for these certain $x_1, x_2$, we can find that 
\begin{equation}
A_2^{-1} = I - \frac{1}{2} x_1 x_1^T - \frac{1}{2} x_2x_2^T.
\end{equation}
Again, we have
\begin{equation}
\|A_2^{-1}x_3\| \leq \|A_2^{-1}\|_2.
\end{equation}
And we can find an eigenvector, which is orthogonal to $x_1$ and $x_2$ (due to $d \ge T$), the equality will be held when setting $x_3$ as this eigenvector:
\begin{equation}
\|A_2^{-1}x_3\| = 1.
\end{equation}
The rest can be done in the same manner.

(2) **When $d < T <= 2d$ , we have 
\begin{equation}
S_{d,T} = d + \frac{T-d}{2} = \frac{T+d}{2}
\end{equation}**

For the first $d$ terms, we still can find $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_T$, which are orthogonal with each other. Thus
\begin{equation}
S_{d,d} = \sum_{i=1}^d \|A_{i-1}^{-1} x_i\|_2 = d.
\end{equation}

For the rest terms, we have to choose $x_1,\dots, x_d$ repeatedly. 
For example, for $i=d+1$, we have
\begin{equation}
A_d^{-1} = I - \frac{1}{2} x_1x_1^T - \dots - \frac{1}{2} x_d x_d^T.
\end{equation}
The eigenvectors of $A_d^{-1}$ are $x_1,\dots,x_d$, and their corresponding eigenvalues are all $\frac{1}{2}$. 
Wlog, we can let $x_{d+1}$ be $x_1$, and in this sense
\begin{equation}
\|A_{d}^{-1}x_{d+1}\| = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
And 
\begin{equation}
A_{d+1}^{-1} = I - \frac{2}{3} x_1x_1^T - \frac{1}{2}x_2x_2^T - \dots - \frac{1}{2}x_dx_d^T.
\end{equation}
The rest can be done in the same manner.

(3) **When $2d < T <= 3d$, ...**

In conclusion, suppose $T$ divided by $d$ has a quotient of $a$ and a remainder of $b$. 
\begin{equation}
S_{d, T} = \sum_{k=1}^a \frac{d}{k} + \frac{b}{a+1}.
\end{equation}